# ASP/Entity: Database is null every time

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

At the end of the if statement, the `busAddr` is always "No address for this type exists..." for everything

**Why this might be?**

```
int counter = 0;
string queryID = "";
List<string> busAddr = new List<string>();
while (counter != busIDs.Count)
{
    queryID = busIDs[counter];
    var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c);
    var address = gathered as tblbus_address;
    var all = address.Address1;
    if (address != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(all[counter].ToString()))
    {
        string test = address.Address1[counter].ToString();
        busAddr.Add(test);
    }
    else
    {
        busAddr.Add("No address for this type exists...");
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line

```
var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c);
```

This returns a queryable. The DB query is not done yet at this point. So you need to trigger it somehow, by calling "ToList", "First" or similar thing that actually requests a value.

Now here

```
var address = gathered as tblbus_address;
```

You are casting this queryable to a item type. Of course this cast is invalid, so the line results in `null`.

To fix it, force the DB query and make sure you cast the right thing. For example:

```
var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c).ToList();
var address = gathered[0] as tblbus_address;
```

Or

```
var gathered = (from c in db.tblbus_address where c.BusinessID == queryID && c.AddressTypeID == addrnum select c);
var address = gathered.First() as tblbus_address;
```

And remember to deal with edge cases, such as no items found.

Comment: Very useful, I used `FirstorDefault();` & that seemed to have fixed it. I also removed the counters in the Index because I only wanted the 1st value coming out the Query. Thankyou @Andrei (Ill mark answer, got to wait another 7mins to do so).

Comment: ` if (address != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Address1))
                {
                    var all = address.Address1;` had to fix this aswell <--